# How to add a callback to a Vue root that triggers when child components update

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Semantic UI sidebar that uses the Semantic UI visibility module to highlight items in the sidebar menu as they're scrolled past in the page. I need to refresh this visibility config every time the page length changes. This happens a lot when my Vue page initially loads and then occasionally as the user adds bits to the page.

I'd like to just be able to add an `updated` callback on the root Vue element and have it trigger every time any descendant component updates but this doesn't seem to be a thing. Is there a way to do this tidily? I'd like not to have to litter a bunch of components with this `updated` callback.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [vue event bus](https://medium.com/vuejobs/create-a-global-event-bus-in-vue-js-838a5d9ab03a) to trigger events from different components.

First, initialize `Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();` in your `main.js` file.

then use it to send events:

`this.$bus.$emit('throw', 'Hi')`

then let your main component listen:

```
this.$bus.$on('throw', ($event) => {
    console.log($event)  //shows 'Hi'
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Capt._Teemo :) I never knew about creating an event bus, but I don't think this solves my particular problem because I'm just replacing my one-liner update callback (that triggers a mutation in the Vuex store) with another one-liner that does something similar. I wonder if it'd be a good feature to allow update events to bubble up? They don't seem to at the moment.